# Having trouble with Geth Node 1.8.2

Tags: mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have been having issues since the geth update. Mist first gave me the error that I should install the newest update manually, and when I downloaded it and tried to install it, I was unsuccessful.

I saw somewhere on here that deleting the old geth.exe file from "%APPDATA%\Ethereum Wallet\binaries\Geth\unpacked" and changing it with the new one would solve the problem, but I am even unable to find this path in my system.

Any answer would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I have meet the same problem.I can't find the path in my system

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem.The path is C:\User\Username\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum Wallet\binaries\Geth\unpacked

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not it either... :/

Comment: @ValentinaNikolic, look for `C:\Users\$YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\EthereumWallet\binaries\Geth\unpacked`, where `$YOUR_USERNAME` is your Windows logon username.